# PhpStorm Local terminal

Tags: php, phpstorm, display

I want to know how can I display the readLine ?

**Local terminal:**
[image]

> 'php' is not recognized as an internal command or external, an executable program or a batch file.

But where can I define this?

**Run window:** runs but no display of readLine ...

[image]

#### My settings

CLI Interpreters:
[image]

Languages > PHP:
[image]

Tools > Terminal:
[image]

Tools > Command Line Tool Support:
[image]

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the PHP to the path environment variables.
in windows use the following path

My Computer->properties -> Advanced system setting -> Environment Variables